# Is there a way to pull from multiple SQL tables for one DataTables table?

Tags: javascript, php, sql-server, datatables-1.10

I use DataTables to present data in a reporting website that I created. I am working on creating a Report Builder where users can select multiple tables and then columns from those tables for a custom report.

What I want to know is whether there's a way to do this with DataTables. I'm able to get the tables names and column names for the custom report, but I've not been able to figure out how to send it to DataTables. I currently use server side processing and send an `ajax` call using `POST` to the DataTable.

I know that I can program in a SQL query based on the selected tables and columns, but I cannot seem to figure out how to have the data sent to DataTables.

Here is how I initialize my DataTables:

```
$(document).ready(function ()
{
    // Setup - add a text input to each footer cell
    $('#DataTable tfoot th').each(function ()           //creates the search bar as the footer
    {
        var title = $(this).text();
        $(this).html('<input type="text" placeholder="Search ' + title + '" />');
    });

    var table = $('#DataTable').DataTable({
        "lengthMenu": [[25, 50, 75, 100, 150, -1], [25, 50, 75, 100, 150, 'All']],
        "dom": '<"top"Bifpl<"clear">>rt<"bottom"ip<"clear">>',
        "buttons": [{
            extend: 'collection',
            text: 'Export',
            buttons: ['export', { extend: 'csv',
                text: 'Export All To CSV',              //Export all to CSV file
                action: function (e, dt, node, config)
                {
                    window.location.href = './ServerSide.php?ExportToCSV=Yes';
                }
            }, 'csv', 'pdf', { extend: 'excel',
                text: 'Export Current Page',            //Export to Excel only the current page and highlight the first row as headers
                exportOptions: {
                    modifier: {
                        page: 'current'
                    }
                },
                customize: function (xlsx)
                {
                    var sheet = xlsx.xl.worksheets['sheet1.xml'];
                    $('row:first c', sheet).attr('s', '7');
                }
            }]
        }
        ],
        "fixedHeader": {                                //Keeps the header and footer visiable at all times
            header: true,
            footer: true
        },
        "select": true,                                 //sets the ability to select rows
        "processing": true,                             //shows the "Processing" when working
        "serverSide": true,                             //sends data to the server for processing
        "ajax": {                                       //where the data is sent and processed
            "url": "./ServerSide.php",
            "type": "POST"
        },
        stateSave: true,                                //Saves the current state of the page
        columnDefs: [{ visible: false, targets: 0}],    //Hides the first column the ID column
        initComplete: function ()                       //sets the search
        {
            var api = this.api();

            // Apply the search
            api.columns().every(function ()
            {
                var that = this;

                $('input', this.footer()).on('keyup change', function (e)
                {
                    if (that.search() !== this.value & e.keyCode == 13) //you have to hit enter for the search to start
                    {
                        that
                          .search(this.value)
                          .draw();
                    }
                });
            });
        }
    });
});

$.fn.dataTable.ext.buttons.export =
{
    className: 'buttons-alert',                         //Adds the "Export all to Excel" button
    id: 'ExportButton',
    text: "Export All To Excel",
    action: function (e, dt, node, config)
    {
        window.location.href = './ServerSide.php?ExportToExcel=Yes';
    }
};
```

Here is what I can currently get to work:
[image]

I'm not sure else anyone would need to help me with this, but if I'm missing something let me know and I'll add it.

I need all the data from all selected tables and columns to be in one DataTables table presented on the website. In the image above I'm showing that I've gotten as far as getting the column headers and using aliases for the tables. I'm working through my *FilterSort.class.pph* file (which is like the *ssp.class.php* in DataTables) to see if I can get it to present the table.

Comment: DataTables is a layer that goes on top of an HTML table. Build the HTML table with PHP and on page load apply the DataTable to that HTML table. Use a JOIN query for multiple DB tables into one display, or use datatables more than once and make multiple datatables for each table. It's not clear what you want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. I was still calling the correct DataTables functions, but I wasn't passing the data to the functions. I ended up having to update my `ServerSide.php` file and my `FilterSort.class.php` file. Those are the ones that all of the other reports use to send data from the server to the screen. After some trial and error, I got it to work and didn't need to change anything in the code posted in my question.